# Honeycomb Gmail Fragment shift

Tags: android, gmail, android-3.0-honeycomb, android-fragments

I'm wondering how when you open a new `Fragment`, you can have the view shift so that the new `Fragment` is centered in your view. In the **Honeycomb** Gmail app we see this when you select an email to open. The list of emails that you can open shifts to the left side of the screen and the email contents is then shown on the right. How do make this shift happen? Thanks.

Comment: I wrote an answer for this over [in this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7339498/fragment-animation-like-gmail-honeycomb-app/9787742#9787742)

Answer (score 2):

You need to animate the `Fragment`.  Check out the following **resources**:

- [Property Animation guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/animation.html)
- [`ObjectAnimator`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/ObjectAnimator.html)
- [`ObjectAnimator` example](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/animation/BouncingBalls.html)
- The new properties on `View` that you can animate such as "width" and "x".

Comment: If your team has a list of possible blog post topics, I'd add one that covers applying these animation effects as part of fragment transactions, which (I presume) is what's happening in Gmail. I looked at this stuff a while back and it made my head hurt, so I was hoping for a smidge of guidance before I dive back in... :-)

Comment: Ive just stumbled across this post, and I am trying to achieve a similar effect.

What I presume is happening, is there are either two activities, which apply fade and slide animations when an email is clicked, or one activity which contains two "container" fragments. When an email is clicked, fade and slide animations are called, and the second container is loaded